# How to draw a 9 x 9 chessboard?

Tags: chess, chessboard

Using the package Chessboard, it is possible to make a drawing of a 9 x 9 chessboard, putting pieces, similar to the following drawing? 
[image]

I tried as follows, but it didn't work.

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{skak,chessboard}

\begin{document}

\newchessgame

\chessboard[pgfstyle=9x9,setwhite={ra1, rb3, rc6, rd2, re4, rf7, rg3, rh5, ri8},showmover=false]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Section 3 (Setting the contents of the board) of the [`chessboard` documentation](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/chessboard/chessboard.pdf) says that to change the size of the board you should use the `maxfield` option. For a 9x9 board, `maxfield=i9` does it.

To make the numbering start at zero, there's a `zero` option, which you can set to `true`. When you use this option, you don't need the `maxfield=i9` anymore because the last place you'll want is `h8`. To change the bottom labels form alphabetic to arabic numbering you can use `labelbottomformat`.

> [image]

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{xskak,chessboard}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{gobble}

\newchessgame

\chessboard[
  % maxfield=i9, % 9x9 board
  zero=true, % numbering starts at zero
  labelbottomformat=\arabic{filelabel}, % bottom labels are numbered with arabic algarisms
  setwhite={ra1, rb3, rc6, rd2, re4, rf7, rg3, rh5, ri8},
  showmover=false
  ]

\end{document}
```

Comment: someone reading my documentation ;-).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer :)

Comment: \newchessgame would be defined it xskak instead of skak is loaded.

Comment: Phelype Oleinik and Ulrike Fischer, Thanks for the help. But, there is still a small problem that I can't solve. The columns and rows, see in the drawing, must be numbered from 0 to 9.

Comment: @BeneditoFreire Sorry for that, I didn't see it. Now it's like in the picture :)

Comment: Numbering 1 .. 9 ? would be 10 columns.

Comment: @albert It matches Benedito's picture... Which is numbered 0--8... Anyhow, with those options it should be easy to change to 1--9 removing the `zero` option, or change to 10x10 adding `maxfield=i9`.

Comment: Sorry, my comment should have been: Numbering 0.. 9? would be 10 columns.

Comment: @albert So far there's the numbering in Benedito's picture, the one in my previous answer, the one in the current answer, the one in Benedito's comment, the one in your comment... My scramble is brained :D

Comment: Your answer is correct just the comment from Benedite wasn't he wants a 9x9 board and later on, with your answer, in a comment, columns 0 to 9.

Comment: @albert I know, I was joking with the amount of version that came up in this post. But thanks for clarifying :)

Comment: @Phelype Oleinik,  excuse me, the numbering is 0 to 8, as in the drawing .

Comment: @BeneditoFreire If you like an answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).