# How to number the row and columns of the chessboard differently?

Tags: chessboard

I learned in the question [How to draw a 9 x 9 chessboard?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/455561/how-to-draw-a-9-x-9-chessboard), answered by Phelype Oleinik, how to distinguish with Arabic numerals the columns and lines of the chessboard. Is it possible to number the rows and columns of the board differently, as in the following figure?
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is. You can change the `printarea` of the board. The argument to `printarea` is `<ll>-<tr>`, where `<ll>` is the lower left corner of the board, and `<tr>` is the top right corner. Since you want the numbering starting from zero, you have to pass the `zero` option. In this case, the zeroth cell gets the special number `Z`. To match your picture, you need `printarea=Z3-e8`:

```
\documentclass{amsart}

\usepackage{chessboard}

\begin{document}

\chessboard[
  printarea=Z3-e8,
  zero=true, % numbering starts at zero
  labelbottomformat=\arabic{filelabel}, % bottom labels are numbered with arabic algarisms
  setwhite={ra3, rb6, rd4, re7},
  showmover=false
  ]

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Comment: Phelype Oleinik, Show!! That's exactly what I wanted. Thanks.